# How can I undo a number from a float

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make a game where you cut down trees and I got stuck on a problem. I want to make a script for the player, that when the player collides with the tree's collider with a istrigger on and press e, an animation starts and the movement speed of the player goes to 0.My question is: How can I undo the speed value when the animation is completed and how can I make the animation play once when the player presses e.

```
 public Animator anim;

 private bool coolDown;
 public float cooldownDuration;

 public PlayerMovement moveSpeed;


void Start()
{
   anim = GetComponent<Animator>(); 
}


private void OnTriggerStay2D(Collider2D other){

    if(!coolDown && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E)){

        anim.Play("topor");
        GetComponent<PlayerMovement>().moveSpeed= 0f;

    }
}

IEnumerator CoolDown(){
coolDown = true;

yield return new WaitForSeconds(cooldownDuration);

coolDown = false;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean when the animation finishes, you want the speed to return to the pre-collision value?

Comment: @Mark Lazz i don't know  what pre-collision means, but I want the speed to go back at the value I put(that's 1 )

Comment: pre-collision = the value moveSpeed before the collision.

Comment: @Mark Lazz oh, thanks, something new, but yea i want the speed value to return to the pre-collision value

Comment: Why is this tagged Unityscript? That's C# code, not Unityscript code (a Javascript derivative created for Unity, but now deprecated in favour of C#).

Answer (score 0):

### Returning pre-collision value

Your options are to either:

- ***EDIT: I just noticed the "Unity" tag on this Question. [See this](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-AnimationWindowEvent.html).***
- Look for a "AnimationComplete" type event on the animation. Write the pre-collision value back into it. i.e.:

```csharp
private void OnTriggerStay2D(Collider2D other){

    if(!coolDown && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E)){

        anim.Play("topor");
        var preColSpeed = GetComponent<PlayerMovement>().moveSpeed;
        anim.Complete += (o,e) => { GetComponent<PlayerMovement>().moveSpeed = preColSpeed; };
        GetComponent<PlayerMovement>().moveSpeed= 0f;

    }
}
```

- If the animation object doesn't have a suitable event, setup a task to check whether the animation has completed every x milliseconds (pick a time that is suitable for the speed). This would be harder work. You'd need a cancellation source and a timeout to make it robust. See the [Task Based Async (TAP) Pattern docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/asynchronous-programming-patterns/task-based-asynchronous-pattern-tap).
- Just set a timer up with suitable time values, and use the Elapsed event, similar to the above.

### Playing the animation once only

Hopefully you can interrogate you "anim" object for whether it is working or not. i.e.

```csharp
private void OnTriggerStay2D(Collider2D other){

    if(anim.Animating) return;

    if(!coolDown && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E)){
        anim.Play("topor");
     etc.
```

Comment: I got this error(  error CS1061: 'Animator' does not contain a definition for 'Complete' and no accessible extension method 'Complete' accepting a first argument of type 'Animator' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?))

Comment: These are suggestions for approaches to investigate in your API. See the edit I made to my response regarding animation events.